# Fetching the particular values from a table onclick of checkbox in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

My table has the following structure
[image]

When i click the particular checkbox.Its should be able to fetch the value of all the contents in the selected checkbox ..It can be n number of products the user selects.How to achieve this .... Thanks for ur time

Source code

```
     <?$this->load->view('admin/header');?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
   function go() {
var frm = document.frm;
var status = inwardProductList['status'];
var statusList = [];
for ( i = 0; i < status.length; i++ ) {
    if ( status[i].checked ) {
        statusList.push('status=' + status[i].value);
    }
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'ajaxUrl?' + statusList.join('&');
   }
  </script>
  <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <form name="inwardProductList" action="" method="post" >
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"  class="formtable">
              <tr>
                <td height="23" colspan="8" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><b>Cart Display</b></td>
              </tr>

   <tr>
     <td height="66" align="left" valign="top"><table width="99%" id="suppliedtable" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <td width="4%" height="43" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Sl.no</strong></td>
            <td width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Product Name</strong></strong></td>
            <td width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Barcode</strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Selection</strong></strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Quantity</strong></strong></td>
           </tr>
<?      
$i=0;
 if($productName->num_rows() >0){

   foreach($productName->result() as $row ){
      $i++; 
    ?>
          <tr>
            <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$i;?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row->product_name?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row->barcode?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><form>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="yes" /> Yes<br /></form></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><form>Quantity: <input type="text" name="Qunatity" /></form></td>          
        </tr>
 <? }}else{?>
    <tr>
                <td height="23" colspan="8" align="center" valign="middle"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><b>Selected product has not been processed yet</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?}?>
  </table></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
  <form><tr><td  align="center" > <button onclick="go()">go</button></td> </tr>
   <div id="test"></div>
    </form></form>
     </form>
```

Comment: not able to fetch the contents of that particular row where i select the product....

Comment: Edit your question and include your source code and I'll see if I can find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved using jquery, something like this, though its off the top of my head so there may be errors.

Jquery stuff

```
$('tr.tableRow > input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).find('td.productName').text();
    var productBarcode = $(this).find('td.productBarcode').text();
    var productQuantity = $(this).find('input[name=productQuantity]').val();

});
```

HTML stuff

```
<tr class="table-row">
    <td class="productName">My Product</td>
    <td class="productBarcode">0389463844</td>
    <td class="productSelected"><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></input></td>
    <td class="productQuantity"><input type="text" name="productQuantity"></td>
</tr>
```